# JQuery Draggable Element Change On Drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a list of items that look like this:

```
<div id="draggablearea">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="title">Title 1</div>
            <div class="content">Content 1.  Probably a few hundred characters</div></li>
        <li> ... </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The "content" div is not visible, because my css includes this:

```
#content {display: none;}
```

Now, I've made them draggable using jquery-ui:

```
$(function(){
    $("#draggablearea li").draggable();
    .... (setting up droppable stuff)
```

So far, so good: everything is appearing on my draggable list, and is moving onto my droppable area as expected.

Now, I want to change the functionality so that on the drop event, the title becomes invisible, and the content becomes visible.

I've tried this:

```
$("#droppableArea").droppable({
    accept: "#draggablearea li",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        ui.draggable.children(".content").appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

But it's not working.  What's the right way to do this?

(The whole `li` is moved to the droppable area when the `appendTo()` is called on the whole `ui.draggable` object.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something more like this?

```
$("#droppableArea").droppable({
    accept: "#draggablearea li",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        ui.draggable.children(".title").hide();
        ui.draggable.children(".content").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the content visible. As you said the whole div was moved so it means contents div is already present in the doppablearea. You just need to it visible by setting its display style to block or inline.

You will have to try something like the following.

```
ui.draggable.children(".content").css("display", "block")
```